# Passing UIImage's to Another View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

My app takes multiple pictures and saves them to disk. I do it to open my second view controller and load all images again to manage them (delete, save, share). I want to cut short and pass images from one view controller to another without saving them but in such a way that app does not crash storing up to 10 images in memory.

How to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are such that they all fit into memory at the same time, you can just pass the `UImage*` from one ViewController to another. If they do not all fit at the same time then you'll be limited to passing only those that fit into memory - the others will have to be "passed" via the disk.